# Custom EditText listview

Tags: java, android, listview

Is there any way to create a custom Listview which contains EditText in each row, and to get each and each EditText value?

Comment: create a listview which contain edittext. loop all position in setOnItemClickListener to get all values!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it.

You can get texts for each row by using TextWatcher or using a button to get current rows text, etc.

First, create a custom layout for each row.
Then create a custom ListView adapter.
Set your adapter to your listView.

[Check this example:](http://www.webplusandroid.com/creating-listview-with-edittext-and-textwatcher-in-android/)

[Another example:](https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/)

Answer (score 0):

u can use ArrayAdapter or baseAdapter to do the same